# A white bar appear between StatusBar and MasterDetailPage Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build a simple geolocalization app, who should point to the location of the user on a map after login. This part works fine, but there is a white space that I'd like to see removed from the status bar and the view, but I don't know how.

Here are two links to screens of the bug:

[image]

[image]

I already tried the solutions presented here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86568/unwanted-blank-space-above-navigation-bar-navigation-page
but it didn't work well: the XAML solutions didn't do anything, and the last solution (with the check on the build version) made the blue bar disappear as well, which is not the researched effect.

Here is some of my code, tell me if you need anything more :

The page where i show my map :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.View.Detail"
             xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             Title=""
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainBackgroundColor}"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
  <StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" Color="Blue"/>
    <maps:Map VerticalOptions ="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions ="FillAndExpand"
            x:Name="MyMap"
            IsShowingUser="true"
            MapType="Street"
        />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the MasterViewDetail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.View.HomePage">

</MasterDetailPage>
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT :

Here is the structure of my project :

```
App(NavigationPage)
    MainPage (ContentPage)
        LoginPage (ContentPage)
            HomePage (MasterDetailPage)
                HomeDetail(ContentPage)
        RegisterPage (ContentPage)
```

The problem is i'm not totally free with it, i'm an intern and must follow the client's command...

Comment: What's your `MainPage` setup? Is it a `NavigationPage`? If yes, change it so that it is a `MasterDetailPage` and then master & detail should be `NavigationPage`s instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built that way inside Xamarin forms - it always adds top padding. A bug has been raised for this, but no idea when it will be fixed.

I've managed to work around it with a custom renderer that does some hacky reflection:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MasterDetailPage), typeof(NoSpaceMasterDetailPageRenderer))]

namespace Droid.Renderers
{
    public class NoSpaceMasterDetailPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// When adding a view, tweak the top padding if necessary.
        /// According to:
        /// https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/589adbd3ef145ec85f9fe64eda008251c1cdb745/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/MasterDetailPageRenderer.cs
        /// The TopPadding is always set for the detail. This works fine when the master detail is shown normally, but
        /// if it is inside a navigation page (such as the inspection view) then you get extra unwanted padding.
        /// The 'fix' is to set the top padding to 0 for the detail, only of course the types and fields are hidden from us...
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="child">Child.</param>
        public override void AddView(Android.Views.View child)
        {
            try
            {
                var isMasterField = child.GetType().GetField("_isMaster", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (isMasterField == null) return;

                var isMaster = isMasterField.GetValue(child);
                if ((bool)isMaster) return;

                var parentField = child.GetType().GetField("_parent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (parentField == null) return;

                var parent = parentField.GetValue(child) as MasterDetailPage;
                if (parent == null || !(parent.Parent is NavigationPage)) return;

                var topPaddingProperty = child.GetType().GetProperty("TopPadding", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (topPaddingProperty != null)
                    topPaddingProperty.SetValue(child, 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                base.AddView(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also try and set a negative padding directly in Forms. No need for a renderer maybe.

Comment: I tried the negative padding, but it only pushed my content under the navigation bar, without interfering with the blank space. [link](http://i.imgur.com/Q5XOTFU.png)

Comment: Also @JimBobBennett , i'm very interested in your answer, but i don't quite understand how it should be used... I suppose the renderer should be placed in the Android project (and not in the Portable project) since it deals with the platform, but how do i use it ?

Comment: Simple - just copy the code into a cs file inside your android project, and that's it. The `ExportRenderer` attribute does all the magic to make it work.